# Python Flask types of showing responses because response is too big

Tags: python, flask

This is my first time using Flask to build an API.
I have a CSV file that I'm reading and storing into a dataframe and then being converted to a dictionary in order to become a response for a Flask API using `flask_restful` to show a JSON output.

The CSV file has around 230000 rows, so when I try to connect to the endpoint it takes to much time to load the data. The data is only fully loaded if I use parameters to filter by date, so the dataframe can show less rows.

If I try to use Postman to test the endpoint I can see that the full load is 120mb of data (only if I change the settings to show more than 50mb), so Power BI or any other tool is not showing all the data as well.

**This is the response I get with full data from the endpoint without parameters (it takes to much time to load):**

[image: Response from endpoint without parameters]

So my question is, is there any other way to show the JSON output from Flask and connect in other tools with this amount of rows?
Endpoint with full data: https://masterdimensions.herokuapp.com/dimensioncalendar
Endpoint with parameters: https://masterdimensions.herokuapp.com/dimensioncalendar?start_dt=2020-01-01&end_dt=2021-12-31

My application:

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import pandas as pd
import os
import pathlib

# Launching an app flask
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, default_mediatype='application/json')

# API class for Index page
class Index(Resource):
    def get(self):
        index_data = [
        {
            "href": "/dimensioncalendar",
            "name": "Dimension Calendar",
            "description": "Dimension Calendar endpoint with date attributes"
        }
        ]
        return (index_data), 200

# API class for DimensionCalendar page
class DimensionCalendar(Resource):
    def get(self):

        # Initialize reparse from Flask
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        # Add arguments
        parser.add_argument('start_dt')
        parser.add_argument('end_dt')
        parser.add_argument('lang')

        args = parser.parse_args()  # parse arguments to dictionary

        # Read CSV file    
        data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.sep, pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), "static", "csv", "DimensionCalendar.csv"))

        # If parameters on API is not null then filter dataframe by start date and end date
        if args['start_dt'] is not None and args['end_dt'] is not None:
            data = data.loc[(data['DT_SHORTDATE'] >= str(args['start_dt'])) & (data['DT_SHORTDATE'] <= str(args['end_dt']))]
        elif args['start_dt'] is not None and args['end_dt'] is None:
            data = data.loc[data['DT_SHORTDATE'] == str(args['start_dt'])]
        
        if args['lang'] == 'pt-BR':
            data.columns = ['DT_DATA', 'NR_ANO', 'NR_MES', 'NR_DIA', 'NM_MES', 'NM_DIADASEMANA', 'NR_MESANO', 'NM_MESANO', 'NM_DATALONGA', 'NR_DIADASEMANA', 'NR_DIADOANO', 'NR_SEMESTRE', 'NM_SEMESTRE', 'NR_QUADRIMESTRE', 'NR_TRIMESTRE', 'NM_TRIMESTRE', 'NR_BIMESTRE', 'NM_BIMESTRE', 'NR_ANORELATIVO', 'NR_MESRELATIVO', 'NR_DIARELATIVO', 'NR_DATA', 'NR_ANOMES', 'NR_ANOTRIMESTRE', 'IC_DIAUTIL', 'IC_FINALDESEMANA', 'IC_FERIADO', 'IC_ANOATUAL', 'IC_MESATUAL', 'IC_DATAATUAL', 'IC_ANOPASSADO', 'IC_MESPASSADO', 'IC_ONTEM', 'LINDATA', 'LINORIGEM']

        # Convert dataframe to dictionary
        data = data.to_dict()
        # Return data and 200 OK code
        return (data), 200

# Case the page is not found
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return "<h1>404</h1><p>The resource could not be found.</p>", 404

# '/dimensioncalendar' is our entry point for DimensionCalendar
api.add_resource(DimensionCalendar, '/dimensioncalendar')
# '/Index' is our entry point for Index
api.add_resource(Index, '/')

# Run our Flask app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Your question isn't really about flask. Its about your tools. If your tools actually wanted all 120mb of data, then this approach is fine- though it'd probably make more sense to just load the csv directly.

Comment: I mentioned Flask wondering if there's any other to show the output instead the way I'm doing. We can load the CSV directly if the user has this option, but what if we want to use the API endpoint just to bring all the data? That's what we are trying to do, using the endpoint URL (you can try by yourself).

Comment: You could put the csv in google docs and just send people the link and get the same result. The question is, "can the tooling your end-users are using interact with the api" - doing things like loading each day's data as needed, or maybe the api doing pre-calculations of some sort. If its not doing those things, I would just stick the file somewhere.